# Ignore bad rows when copying data from Blob to Azure SQL via C# .NET Framework managed Data Factory

Tags: c#, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory

I am following [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/tutorial-copy-data-dot-net) to load data in Azure SQL from a flat file in a Blob.

This method requires a C# .NET Framework console app to create / manage the Blob dataset, Azure SQL sink, and Data Factory.

The only problem is that with big, messy data files I inevitably encounter some rows which contain an extra delimiter or which are somehow otherwise malformed. The data is too big to clean locally before the upload to the blob.

A normal solution is to ignore the bad rows, i.e. to [allow fault tolerance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-fault-tolerance).

There's an example of how to do this with JSON:

```
"typeProperties": {
    "source": {
        "type": "BlobSource"
    },
    "sink": {
        "type": "SqlSink",
    },
    "enableSkipIncompatibleRow": true,
    "redirectIncompatibleRowSettings": {
         "linkedServiceName": {
              "referenceName": "<Azure Storage or Data Lake Store linked service>",
              "type": "LinkedServiceReference"
            },
            "path": "redirectcontainer/erroroutput"
     }
}
```

However, I haven't been able to determine if there is some equivalent for this in C#. I tried modifying my original connection string for the Azure SQL sink from this:

```
    // Specify the sink Azure SQL Database information
    string azureSqlConnString =
        "Server=tcp:mydb.database.windows.net,1433;" +
        "Database=mydb;" +
        "User ID=myuser;" + 
        "Password=mypassword;" + 
        "Trusted_Connection=False;Encrypt=True;Connection Timeout=30";
    string azureSqlTableName = "dbo.mytable";

    string storageLinkedServiceName = "AzureStorageLinkedService";
    string sqlDbLinkedServiceName = "AzureSqlDbLinkedService";
    string blobDatasetName = "BlobDataset";
    string sqlDatasetName = "SqlDataset";
    string pipelineName = "Adfv2TutorialBlobToSqlCopy";
```

to this:

```
    // Specify the sink Azure SQL Database information
    string azureSqlConnString =
        "Server=tcp:mydb.database.windows.net,1433;" +
        "Database=mydb;" +
        "User ID=myuser;" + 
        "Password=mypassword;" + 
        "enableSkipIncompatibleRow= true;" + 
        "Trusted_Connection=False;Encrypt=True;Connection Timeout=30";
    string azureSqlTableName = "dbo.mytable";

    string storageLinkedServiceName = "AzureStorageLinkedService";
    string sqlDbLinkedServiceName = "AzureSqlDbLinkedService";
    string blobDatasetName = "BlobDataset";
    string sqlDatasetName = "SqlDataset";
    string pipelineName = "Adfv2TutorialBlobToSqlCopy";
```

as a guess, but it didn't work:

> "message":
>   "ErrorCode=UserErrorInvalidDbConnectionString,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=Invalid
>   database connection string provided. Check the connection string at
>   'Sink'
>   side.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary,''Type=System.ArgumentException,Message=Keyword
>   not supported: 'enableskipincompatiblerow'.,Source=System.Data,'",

Is there a way to do this?

The `SkipErrorFile` [property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.datafactory.models.copyactivity?view=azure-dotnet) of `CopyActivity` class says it gets or sets fault tolerance. I got the `CopyActivity` implementation to accept the property with `SkipErrorFile = new SkipErrorFile { }` but it did not seem to change the behavior in the desired way.

Comment: I checked Copy Activity class and it seems not support `enableSkipIncompatibleRow`. I think you might validate the source dataset (blob) before going initiate the pipeline of CopyActivity. Basically it still run validate from their library in your application if it's supported

Comment: @TấnNguyên The property `SkipErrorFile` sounds like it should work, but my attempt to set it did not have the desired result. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.datafactory.models.copyactivity?view=azure-dotnet

Comment: What I've done as a workaround is to load everything into 1 column (I used a fake delimiter) then parse the columns in SQL and Databricks afterwards, since it was too big to work on with my laptop before loading it to the Blobs.

Comment: Yes that's also a way if device so lagging. Anyway, congrats !!

Answer (score 0):

I have a workaround but not a true solution, so I'm going to self-answer but not select my answer as the solution.

The workaround is to create a fake delimiter (one that does not exist in the data, like `\t\t`) and a Azure SQL sink table with only 1 column.

From there I can load the data into a single column and, after it is in Azure SQL, parse it with either SQL or any language in Databricks (Python, R, Scala or SQL) so that I can use the HPC cloud environment to clean and parse the data at scale.